# Передача вектора строк в функцию

Tags: c++, строки, vector

Нужно из одной функции перенести `vector<string>` в другую функцию и работать там с ней.

Я смог провернуть такое с данными типа `int`, а вот со `string` не выходит.

```
std::string fun(std::string);

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> arr(3);
    fun(arr);
    std::cout << "Сумма: " << fun(arr);
    system("pause");
}

std::string fun(std::string arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            std::cout << "[" << i + 1 << "] ";
            std::cin >> arr[i];
        }
    return arr;
}
```

P.S. Я знаю, что у меня в коде ошибка, хочу просто понять суть как передать содержимое вектора в функцию.

Comment: Ваша функция ожидает string, а вы ей vector передаёте. Измените тип аргумента.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше всего передавать по ссылке. Представьте, что получается при передаче по значению - копируется каждая строка, идет выделение кучи памяти (весьма медленная операция)... И потом - что бы вы ни делали с этим вектором строк в функции - это на оригинале не отразится. Иногда это совсем не то, что надо. Так что я рекомендую

```
std::string fun(std::vector<std::string>& arr)
```

если вам нужно как-то менять этот вектор и строки, или

```
std::string fun(const std::vector<std::string>& arr);
```

если `arr`, если менять не надо.

В Вашем конкретном случае - первый вызов вообще полностью теряет все введенное, второй возвращает тот же вектор - т.е. очередное копирование всего при возврате! (Я пока молчу, что `std::cout << "Сумма: " << fun(arr);` не скомпилируется за отсутствием оператора вывода для вектора строк). После этого у вас есть вектор, возвращенный функцией `fun(arr)`, и вектор `arr`, который не имеет к этому возвращенному вектору *никакого отношения*.

Словом, в этом вашем коде передача аргумента *только как неконстантной ссылки*.

Comment: Нет там копирования при возврате. Или Вы про свой вариант со ссылкой?

Comment: я бы проверил, будет там rvo или нет

Comment: @ixSci в до `c++11` режиме копирование вполне может быть. С `c++11` будет перемещение.

Comment: @ixSci  std::string fun(std::string arr) - в общем случае (до С++11) будет копирование; RVO - приятная возможность, но не ОБЯЗАННОСТЬ компилятора.

Comment: @alexolut, для меня C++ до 2014 года не существует, если явно не указано в вопросе. Не вижу смысла упоминать старые версии, вообще.

Comment: @Harry, начиная с С++17 это __обязанность__. NRVO — нет, RVO — да.

Comment: @ixSci В тегах нет c++11; пока еще c++17 не принят; впрочем, это в любом случае академические споры о деталях, которые для данного вопроса несущественны. Кстати, сейчас читаю интересную книжицу Guntheroth, "Optimized C++", там про это (передачу, возврат, все эти оптимизации) написано много интересного, а главное - *неожиданного*, рекомендую :)

Comment: @ixSci Мы кажется уже обсуждали этот момент не так давно. Просто `c++` сильно изменился с выходом 11 Стандарта, по сути стал чуть ли не другой язык, поэтому если метки `c++11` или выше нет в коде, я предпочитаю опираться на более старый Стандарт. Кто знает, по каким справочникам ТС там учит язык. Ну или давайте подредактируем описание метки `c++` чтоб её упоминание стоило рассматривать именно как код в последней принятой версии Стандарта на момент публикации вопроса.

Comment: @alexolut Здравая идея. Ввести c++03, подразумевая заодно и c++98, и считать просто c++ - максимальным из текущих?

Comment: @Harry, хм, орейли это классно, но 50 долларов, точно стоит?

Comment: @alexolut, это нужно обсудить. Давайте сделаем голосование на мете и в чате С++ это отметим. Если у кого-нибудь есть возможность — создайте, пожалуйста. Если нет, то я вечером сам создам.

Comment: @ixSci Ну... как говорится, есть места, где она в виде pdf :) Я только не уверен, что тут можно обсуждать такие рыбные места...

Comment: @Harry, я всё-таки предпочитаю покупать книги. Вы читали Мэйерса последнего? Есть там что-то новое, чего нет в Мэйерсе и у Страуструпа?

Comment: @ixSci Видите ли, эта книга как раз скорее перпендикулярна Мейерсу и Страуструпу. В том, что там встречаются советы, против которых восстает все, чему учили :) - типа, что часто лучше отказаться от той же string и использовать строки C, или что интеллектуальные указатели - не совсем хорошая вещь. Т.е. если Мейерс и Страуструп - это скорее как писать программы быстро, то Гантерот - как писать программы быстрые... Я не могу рекомендовать вам покупку, просто потому, что слишком большая ответственность - 50$ - по крайней мере у нас это почти треть средней зарплаты по стране :(

Answer (score 3):

Вот пример с передачей по ссылке. Возвтат строки для этой функции по моему мнению не нужен.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const vector<string> &v)
{
    for(auto const& s: v)  os << s << " ";
    return os;
}

void fun(vector<string>& arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "[" << i + 1 << "] ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> arr(3);
    fun(arr);
    cout << "result=" << arr << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

выдаст:

```
[1] 123
[2] 456
[3] 789
result=123 456 789
```

Answer (score -2):

`std::string fun(std::string arr) //функция принимает строку`

`std::string fun(std::vector<std::string> arr) //функция принимает вектор строк`

Comment: вроде получилось но есть пару ошибок (моя вина естественно))) спасибо, буду дальше залипать и делать :)

Comment: Человек *меняет* в функции значение вектора - передача по значению тут (даже если игнорировать все прочие факторы) не годится.

Comment: он вопрос задал - я ответил, может быть еще и про  range based loop написать?

Comment: @strangeqargo Вы ответили, как бы это сравнить... Как пройти на соседнюю улицу? Да вот там сесть на автобус, проехать 5 остановок, потом пересесть на троллейбус, еще 4 остановки. Это - тоже добраться на соседнюю улицу, но неэффективно, а главное, не туда, куда надо.

Comment: @strangeqargo да вы что, это же полное копирование всего вектора. Никогда не передавайте вектор по значению, если копирование явно не требуется. И то, лучше передать по ссылке и скопировать внутри функции

Comment: @Harry оспорю:  1) вот этот ответ - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592630/is-pass-by-value-a-reasonable-default-in-c11 2) человек спрашивал не про эффективность, а почему не работает. Как передать. Он забыл про тип, а вы начинаете учить его эффективной передаче по ссылке

Comment: @strangeqargo Учиться хорошему никогда не рано :) Тем более что для его кода передача по значению *просто не работает*...