# Переменные в c++

Tags: c++, массивы

Недавно столкнулся с проблемой по поводу использовании переменных в функции. 
В коде у меня есть массив was[n][m] который надо использовать в одной функции, но компилятор сообщает об ошибке. Пожалуйста подскажите как решить проблему.
Вот код

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void search(int i, int j){
    if (was[i][j]) cout << 1;
}

int main(){
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    int was[n][m];
    was[0][0] = 1;
    search(0, 0);
}
```

Требуется использовать массив в функции search()

Comment: Ваша главная проблема - использовать то, что в С++ отсутствует. `    cin >> n >> m;
    int was[n][m];` - это можно только в качестве нестандартного расширения С++, так что вы даже не можете использовать глобальный массив (как хотели). Если позарез нужен именно массив `int[][]`, а не вектор векторов - указывайте его размеры во время компиляции. Или стройте динамический массив `int**`.

Comment: сменил массив на вектор векторов 'vector <vector<int>> was(n, vector<int>(m, 1));' , но все равно есть ошибка

Comment: Ну так `was` в функцию не передается. А вообще вместо "двухмерного" массива практически всегда следует использовать одномерный из ВxШ элементов с соотв. идексацией. Еще `bits/stdc++.h` не является стандартным заголовком

Comment: А как передавать вектор was в функцию?

Comment: @Pcoder [массив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/136769/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E), [вектор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572699/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E)

Comment: Все засолвил проблему.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` - это вселенское зло, особенно рядом с `using namespace std;`. [Раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: `int was[n][m]` - динамический массив на стеке - это фича языка C, но не C++. В C++ эту фичу портировать не стали по вполне определённым соображениям (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458857/why-doesnt-c-support-dynamic-arrays-on-the-stack).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Зачем так пугать? `using namespace` приемлемо для небольших и главное, не заголовочных, файлов. Некоторые люди просто медленно печатают. Хотя я предпочитаю всегда квалифицировать явно. Да и IDE помогают лучше, если начинать печатать с `std::`.

Comment: @DmitryT. Заметьте, злом я назвал `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, а не `using namespace std;`. :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Тут я спорить не буду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) У вас ошибка в объявлении массива. Например, это не будет работать на компиляторе MS Visual C++.

2) Массив `was` объявлен локально в функции `int main`, в функции `search` он будет недоступен

Мой вариант:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int** was;

void search(int i, int j)
{
    if (was[i][j]) 
        cout << 1;
}

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;

    was = (int**) calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        was[i] = (int*)calloc(m, sizeof(int));

    was[0][0] = 1;
    search(0, 0);
}
```

Так же, вы можете передавать was в функцию, во избежание использования глобальных переменных

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот, примерно так:

```
using namespace std;

void search(const vector<vector<int>& was, int i, int j)
{
    if (was[i][j]) cout << 1;
}

int main(){
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector<vector<int> was(n, vector<int>(m));
    was[0][0] = 1;
    search(was, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1)Здравствуйте, Ваша функция "не видит" массив, т.к. он находится в другой функции int main() .Объявите массив глобально, т.е. сразу после "using namespace std;".
2)Размер статического массива в c++ не может быть переменным значением, а только константным.